# Comparing a single point in two time series

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance

I have two time series of males and females traveling from point A in between 1979 to 2001. The question is, is there a significant difference in the number of male and female travelers in year, say, 2000?

How can I answer this question?

Also, would it be different if I had the data divided by destination, i.e females and males traveling from A to B, from A to C, etc.?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a significant difference in the number of male and female travelers in year, say, 2000?

Your question could be interpreted in two ways:

1. assessing a difference between the number of male and female travelers in a given year;
2. assessing the variation in the male and female traveler series over time, focusing on a particular data point (is it an "outlier"?).

I will focus on **interpretation 1.**

In interpretation 1., the time series dimension becomes irrelevant since you are only considering one time point.
Denote the number of male and female travelers $n_m$ and $n_f$, respectively. Then your question is, is $n_m$ significantly different from  $n_f$?

- If the numbers are measured *without* error, then we cannot really talk about statistical significance. $n_m$ is simply different from $n_f$ unless $n_m=n_f$. If you mean *subject-matter* significance, you have to decide yourself what a significant difference is (10 units, 1% or yet something else).
- If the numbers are measured *with* error and the error distribution is know or can be estimated from the data (additional data would be needed besides the two time series you mentioned), you could apply a statistical test (something like a $t$-test) to determine whether the difference is statistically significant.

> Would it be different if I had the data divided by destination, i.e females and males traveling from A to B, from A to C, etc.?

There would be no major conceptual difference, but in the case of numbers measured *with* error you could probably have richer information on the error distribution (if that is available for each destination and jointly). Also, you could test a broader variety of hypotheses (destination-specific, combining destinations) if that interests you.